# Efficient way to generate fixed length fields flat file - T-SQL or SSIS package with flat-file as destination

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Do you think that this is an efficient method to generate a record with fixed length fields using T-SQL SQL Server 2012?

```
INSERT INTO #RECORD AS
SELECT 
 RIGHT('0000000000' + RTRIM(field01), 10) 
+RIGHT('          ' + RTRIM(field02), 10)
+RIGHT('00000' + RTRIM(field03),6)
+ etc ...
+RIGHT('0000000000' + RTRIM(fieldnn, 10) 
FROM sourceTable
```

OR should I use SSIS package with `sourceTable` and `Flat-fileAsdestination` and with mapped and derived fields.

Comment: Normally you can't export to a file from T-SQL so the alternatives are not really the same. T-SQL + bcp is a good solution unless you are comfortable with SSIS

Answer (score 2):

If your dataset is not that big from performance perspective it doesn't really matter if you export data with T-SQL, SISS package or whatever. If it just a one-time task you'd better use `Management Studion` to do it. Just right click the database go to `Tasks->Export Data...`. In the wizard choose the source database and table. Then choose flat file as a destination. There you can also choose the format. Among the options the one you need that is `Fixed length`. On the `Configure Flat File Destination` step you can `Edit Mappings` to set the columns to export and what their length should be.

If your dataset is large and/or you want to automate the process you should consider using [bcp  utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802) which also supports fixed width file formats.

Can't say your solution is bad or won't work but it's just bugs prone to me and would be hard to support if you gonna do it on ragular basis.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @user3504427 hi there, you didn't make any comments to my answer, just wonder if it was helpful to you? If not is there is anything I can do to help you with your question?

Comment: Excellent answer which I have upvoted. Unfortunately it seems lately that people post questions on here but never get around to finishing them. I'm now in the habit of posting a comment to gauge the OP's interest before I make any real effort.